# How can I convert a row from a dataframe in pyspark to a column but keep the column names? - pyspark or python

Tags: python

I have an array where it is made up of several arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zip the list and then call the dataframe constructor:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(zip(*all_data), cols)
```

---

```
df.show(truncate=False)
+-----------------------------+-----------+
|name                         |chromossome|
+-----------------------------+-----------+
|NM_019112.4(ABCA7):c.161-2A>T|19p13.3    |
|CCL2, 767C-G                 |17q11.2-q12|
+-----------------------------+-----------+
```

Or with `zip_longest`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
df = spark.createDataFrame(zip_longest(*all_data,fillvalue=''),cols)
df.show()
```